# Печать фиксированных документов WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, печать

Можете посоветовать какие-либо книги или другую информацию о печати фиксированных (содержимое документа не изменяет своих размеров и остается одинаковым при работе или печати на любом устройстве) документов в WPF C#. Посоветовать о там как нужно правильно создавать такие документы и работать с ними. В интернете не особо много понятной и структурированной информации на эту тему. Мне необходимо создать отчёт на листе A4 с таблицами и возможностью добавления новых листов, если содержимое не помещается на один лист. И ещё возможность сменить ориентацию листа с книжной на альбомную и наоборот.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Что такое фиксированные документы и чем они отличаются от нефиксированных?

Comment: Фиксированный документ всегда одинаково отображается на всех устройствах без изменения размера своего содержимого. А потоковый (нефиксированный) документ подстраивает свое содержимое под разрешения экранов разных устройств.

Comment: @aepot, думаю речь про это: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/documents-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8